# How to define generic variable in spring context

Tags: spring

In my application I have defined mapper like this:

```
  JsonXMLMapper<MyClass> mapper = new JsonXMLMapper<MyClass>(
            MyClass.class);
```

How I can rewrite this variable in spring context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `contructor-arg` to instantiate your bean

```
<bean id="mapper" class="full.package.name.JsonXMLMapper">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="mypackage.MyClass"/>
</bean>
```

You don't have to worry about the generic parameter as it is not relevant at runtime.

Comment: are  you sure about '.class' suffix ? because this gives me error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [my.package.MyClass.class]

Comment: I am not sure, did you try without it ? I will update my answer accordingly.